# How a LinkedList Keeps Track of All Nodes - C#?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have been struggling trying to develop my own singly linked list, I cant understand how a node is inserted at the end of a Linked List?

Here's the code:

```
class LinkedList
{
    private Node head;

    public void AddLast(int value)
    {
        if (head == null)
        {
            head = new Node();

            head.value = value;
            head.next = null;
        }
        else
        {
            Node temp = new Node();
            temp.value = value;

            Node current = head;

            while (current.next != null)
            {
                current = current.next;
            }

            current.next = temp;
        }
    }

    public void PrintAll() 
    {
        Node current = head;

        while (current != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(current.value);
            current = current.next;
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the main method

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
        list.AddLast(3);
        list.AddLast(5);
        list.AddLast(4);
    }
```

1) I totally get the first part list.AddLast(3). Since head is null, we create a new node head and assign values to it.

2) When list.AddLast(5) is called, head is no more null, and thus we create a new temporary node, assign values to it. NOW we create a new node current which holds values of Head, it is to be noted Head.Next was null.

Now we iterate through current and place our temp node to current.Next.

3) Now, Upon calling list.AddLast(5) shouldn't the current be again overwritten with the contents of Head? which was Head.Value = 3 and Head.Next = Null.

So shouldn't it current.Value = 3 and Current.Next = Null? And if not then why?

Comment: Use BCL [LinkedList<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx) and you don't have to worry about it

Comment: This works too but I don't get why, and I am learning to make my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Node current = head;
```

When the above statement executes, `current` is assigned only the reference of `head` temporarily and not the value. So `current` only points to `head` at that moment. `current.value` will give you the value for `head` if executed after this statement.

```
while (current.next != null)
{
    current = current.next;
}
```

Now, when the above `while` loop executes, it iterates through the linked list and takes the current node to the last node in the linked list which will have `current.next = null`.

```
current.next = temp;
```

When the above statement executes, the new node is added to the last of the linked list.

Comment: So it points to that only? But will the changes in current effect in head? Aren't what you saying similar to this?

            int a = 2;
            int b = a;

            b = 4;

            Console.WriteLine(a);

But the value of a here remains the same //2

Comment: You have given an example of value type variables but `current` i believe is a reference type variable. In case of value type the actual value is stored in the variable itself. In case of reference type variable, the variable doesn't contain the actual value but an address to a memory location where the actual value is present. So `current = head` does not set the actual value of `current` to value of `head`. Instead it changes the memory address stored in `current` to the memory address stored in `head`

Comment: see this http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-value-type-and-reference-type

Comment: Thanks a lot, classes a reference types, structs are value types, totally forgot them. Thanks a looooooot.

Answer (score 0):

There are oodles of implementations of linked lists. However for a simple singlely Linked list we think of it like thus

[image]

If i understand you correctly, this is the part you don't understand

```
// All this part of the method does is add the new value to the end of the list

// create node
Node temp = new Node();
// assign its value
temp.value = value;

// now we want to start with the head and follow 
// the chain until we find the last node
Node current = head;
// has it got a next element
while (current.next != null)
{
    // if so change current to next and look again
    current = current.next;
}

// yay no more nexts, lets add temp here
current.next = temp;

// you have effectively added your new element to the end of the list
```

On saying that another common implementation is to save the `Last`/`Current` Node in the class (just like you did with head).

In that case, instead of iterating through the chain we can reference that *Node* and just add to its next and update `Last` reference in the class. However when we have to remove the last item, we have to remember not only to `null` `Last` in the class but `null` its parents `Next` reference as well.

The only way to do this is once again iterate the chain.

To make that easier we can implement a doubly linked list so its easier to find its parent

[image]

**Update**

> what I don't understand is that why isn't the link to next nodes lost
>   when current who holds that info is updated every time with content of
>   Head.

In the above, think of `current` as just a temporary variable, its sole job in life is just like a temporary marker of the next link in the chain,

When we call this

```
current = current.next;
```

All its doing its grabbing whats in `current.next` and holding on to it for the loop condition again. We can call this without destroying whats in `current.next`

On the last time, when we have found nothing in `current.next`
i.e when the loop checks that `current.next== null` we can safely put our temp node into it `current.next = temp;` <== it was empty anyway

Comment: Thanks a lot TheGeneral for the explanation, what I don't understand is that why isn't the link to next nodes lost when current who holds that info is updated every time with content of Head.

Answer (score 0):

You create a new instance of `LinkedList`.

`list.AddLast(3);` --> `head` is `null`, you create a new `Node` and assign it to `head`.

`list.AddLast(5);` --> Create a new `Node` `temp` and assigns `5` to the value. Keep in mind that `head`'s `value` = `3` and `next` is `null`. A new variable is created called `current` that points to `head`. The `while` then traverses the tree and if `current`'s `next` is not null, then reassign `current`'s `next` to that `node`. In this case, the `while` loop is not run because `head`'s `next` is null, so all it does is just assign `head.next` to your `current` node. At this point we have `head.value = 3`, `head.next = new Node(5, null);`

`list.AddLast(4);` --> Same as above but the `while` loop now runs. It traverses all the way to find a `Node` that has no `next` value and assigns `4` to it. At this point we have `head.value = 3, head.next = new Node(5, new Node(4, null))`