# Undestanding Basic LinkedList

Tags: c#, .net, linked-list

I'm trying to wrap my head around linked lists and I have this code sample here:

```
public class SinglyLinkedListNode {
    public int data;
    public SinglyLinkedListNode next;

    public SinglyLinkedListNode(int data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public void Print() {
        Console.WriteLine(data);
        if(next != null) {
            next.Print();
        }
    }
}

public class SinglyLinkedList {
    public SinglyLinkedListNode headNode;

    public SinglyLinkedList() {
        headNode = null;
    }

    public void Print() {
        if(headNode != null) {
            headNode.Print();
        }
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        SinglyLinkedList list = new SinglyLinkedList();
        int listCount = 5;
        for(int i = 0; i < listCount; i++) {
            int listItem = i + 1;
            SinglyLinkedListNode list_head = InsertNodeAtTail(list.headNode, listItem);
            list.headNode = list_head;
        }

        list.Print();
    }

    static SinglyLinkedListNode InsertNodeAtTail(SinglyLinkedListNode head, int data) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new SinglyLinkedListNode(data);
            return head;
        } else {
            var temp = head;
            while (temp.next != null) {
                temp = temp.next;
            }

            temp.next = new SinglyLinkedListNode(data);
            return head;
        }
    }
}
```

in the InsertNodeAtTail method in the else statement where it's basically storing the passed in headNode as a temp variable and at the very end of it it set the temp variables next pointer to the new data were passing in and then return head. In this scenario how does head track the changes in the temp variable?

When I debug this and check the return head value it has all the changes that I've done to the temp variable but the head value was never really modified/used besides the part where it's being assigned to the temp variable.

Example is let's say we got a list 1 -> 3 -> 5 -> and were adding in 6 
6 gets added into the temp.next and on return head, the head value contains 1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 6 but we've never done anything to head? All changes were to the temp variable.

Sorry if this might be a stupid question but I'm just not getting how this works.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51700696/how-a-linkedlist-keeps-track-of-all-nodes-c/51700882#51700882

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I debug this and check the return head value it has all the changes that I've done to the temp variable but the head value was never really modified/used besides the part where it's being assigned to the temp variable.

`temp` is a reference to an `SinglyLinkedListNode`.

When you call the following code it keeps changing the reference of `temp` to the next `SinglyLinkedListNode` in the chain until you reach the last node. At this point `temp` is referring to the 5 in your example, and appends your new 6 to the end. No change is made to the head.

Since it is a chain 1 -> 3 -> 5, adding 6 to the end affects the whole chain and now becomes 1-> 3 -> 5 -> 6.

```
var temp = head;

while (temp.next != null) {
    temp = temp.next;
}
```

Comment: Ahhh yes okay thanks, I completely looked over the fact that its being passed as a reference type and not value. Thanks!